How do mass and velocity relate to momentum?
So this is more of a clarifying question. A lot of online definitions state that momentum is a measure of how hard it is to stop or swerve an object, which makes sense. However, the formula for momentum is mass times velocity, and I'm just wondering how the individual components (mass and velocity, that is) make the object harder to stop.
Also, are objects with more mass harder to stop because they have more inertia, or is there another reason?
Thanks.

Does this answer your question? Explain Momentum

Does this answer your question? What is momentum really?

A force  induces a change in momentum. Because momentum is mass multiplied by velocity, that basically means that the faster an object is, or the more mass it has, then the larger the momentum and then the more force you will need to slow it down a given amount. Or, alternatively, use the same force for a longer time.

I think a better description for momentum is, how much "oomph" an object has.
A non moving object clearly has zero oomph.
A heavier(faster) object has more important than a lighter(slower) one. This is all reflected on the formula $\vec p=m \vec v$.
To change how much oomph an object has, a force is required. $\vec F= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\vec p=m \vec a$.
Since velocity is a vector quantity, it has a magnitude and a direction. To stop an object, you decrease the magnitude. The force required is proportional to the mass of the object and the change in magnitude, as can be seen from the formula.
To deflect an object, your change the direction. Same as above, the required force is proportional to the mass and change in velocity direction.

Essentially, objects with more velocity are harder to stop because they have a greater magnitude?

Because they are moving faster, you have to slow them down more. But the more massive they are, the harder they are to slow down. Hence, both factors are critical to why momentum relates to the force.
